# How to inline a button next to input field in form-group and form-row class (bootstrap 4)?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, button, bootstrap-4

I am struggling with bootstrap classes in form fields.

When I want to add a button inline next to an input field, it will either - go below the input or wont stay inline (line height wise).

I would like to have a button next to password field. I am already using form-row and form-group classes to organise the inputs, but dont mind using other classe providing the effect is the same or as similar as to what I have now

See code below:

```
<div class="card mt-4">
  <div class="card-body">
    <form>
      <div class="form-row">
      <div class="form-group col-12 col-md-4">
        <label for="email">Email</label>
        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Email" autocomplete="off">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group col-12 col-md-4">
        <label for="password">Password</label>
        <input type="password" class="form-control mr-1" id="password" placeholder="Password" autocomplete="new-password">
          <div class="form-group input-group-btn col-12 col-md-4">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary"> Go! </button>
          </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

and link to codepen:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MNoPdX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Popper JS -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="card mt-4">
  <div class="card-body">
    <form>
      <div class="form-row">
      <div class="form-group col-12 col-md-4">
        <label for="email">Email</label>
        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Email" autocomplete="off">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group col-12 col-md-4">
        <label for="password">Password</label>
        <input type="password" class="form-control mr-1" id="password" placeholder="Password" autocomplete="new-password">

    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-12 col-md-4" style="margin-top:30px">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary"> Go! </button>
    </div>
  </div>
  </form>
  </div>
</div>
```